Issue with Hashicorp Vault policies and globbing
I have the following policies defined in my terraform file:
policies = {
  ops = {
      "*" = {
        capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "patch", "list", "sudo"]
      }
      "secretstuff/data/*" = {
        capabilities = ["deny"]
      }
  }
}

I read this as I should be able to do almost anything other than get the contents of a secret stored in the secretstuff KV mount. The KV mount is using v2 (from what I'm able to gather).
Post login this is what I see, which looks to be expected:
# vault token lookup
...
policies  [default ops]
...

# vault policy read ops
path "*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "patch", "list", "sudo"]
}

path "secretstuff/data/*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}

But when I try getting the value of a secret, I'm actually allowed to. I would have expected a 403 here:
# vault kv get secretstuff/some/sub/dirs/key
// no permissions error, key value returned along with metadata

What is going on? I've been debugging this for a while and can't seem to make sense of it.
I'm expecting that trying to read this data would fail, but it doesn't.

Am I missing something. The path your denying is secretstuff but the path your accessing is supersecret. Not sure why you expect this to be denied when they don't match the deny capability

@ChrisDoyle that's a me problem. I censored the path. Fixing now.

What does the token capabilities path show. This will evaluate a vault path against the policies of the token.  https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/token/capabilities

@ChrisDoyle it shows the capabilities under *, basically all of them. I would have expected deny or nothing at all

@ChrisDoyle its almost as if the kv store is acting like it was v1, but I've confirmed it's v2

You can confirm the acting entity's attached policy is ops?

@MatthewSchuchard that's correct when I check my token info, I see that the ops policy is applied. Then when I list the ops policy I confirm the two rules are present.

Unable to reproduce, works on my machine. I used the root token to create and log in with another token vault login $(vault token create --format json --policy default --policy ops | jq -r '.auth["client_token"]'). Also created an ops2 policy to grant access to have a successful/opposite test.

While I don't think this is an answer its too long to write in a comment and I believe may give more value to the OP. My setup here is a single vault instance using userpass auth engine.
I have created the same ops policy
$ vault policy read ops
path "*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "patch", "list", "sudo"]
}

path "secretstuff/data/*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}


I have assigned the ops policy to a new user ops_test
$ vault read auth/userpass/users/ops_test
Key                        Value
---                        -----
token_bound_cidrs          []
token_explicit_max_ttl     0s
token_max_ttl              0s
token_no_default_policy    false
token_num_uses             0
token_period               0s
token_policies             [ops]
token_ttl                  0s
token_type                 default

I then login as the ops_test user
$ vault login --method=userpass username=ops_test
Password (will be hidden):
Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below
is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"
again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.

Key                    Value
---                    -----
token                  hvs.CAESIAdy2QhNWcRYegJpUglHR1x7r_3JO5qX-OnAcVyjQtYNGh4KHGh2cy44WlZRc0hKUFhUd2RqSzhRNUhUYmRWYzI
token_accessor         1RDKHDF8KVpTdB0jGey5fSr3
token_duration         768h
token_renewable        true
token_policies         ["default" "ops"]
identity_policies      []
policies               ["default" "ops"]
token_meta_username    ops_test

I get the ops policy and also the default policy thats allocated to all tokens. If I try to read from the secretstuff kv2 engine, I correctly get denied
$ vault kv get secretstuff/foo
Error reading secretstuff/data/foo: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secretstuff/data/foo
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
        * permission denied

If I check the journalctl audit logs I can see in the response I was denied as seen in the policy result.
{
  "auth": {
    "accessor": "hmac-sha256:8f2f0506e37dbd0d1d0116f68ce155c41b6d7efa841fb6afb1697b179daa6ce6",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:d011436b2aa7d8e56bf1f466e2488cb986c326890f12a5896c3a3b13288c59eb",
    "display_name": "userpass-ops_test",
    "entity_id": "58a235d9-5f6d-3158-d64f-2af898e4bae7",
    "metadata": {
      "username": "ops_test"
    },
    "policies": [
      "default",
      "ops"
    ],
    "policy_results": {
      "allowed": false
    },
    "token_policies": [
      "default",
      "ops"
    ],
    "token_issue_time": "2024-08-09T17:37:43Z",
    "token_ttl": 2764800,
    "token_type": "service"
  },
  "error": "1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n",
  "request": {
    "client_id": "58a235d9-5f6d-3158-d64f-2af898e4bae7",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:8f6476600ebd3fb62b9d62381a5f87d7ef7eab66950cb37845575b232ce21e13",
    "client_token_accessor": "hmac-sha256:8f2f0506e37dbd0d1d0116f68ce155c41b6d7efa841fb6afb1697b179daa6ce6",
    "id": "6f9b92eb-74f7-fada-c62b-044bbcb87056",
    "mount_class": "secret",
    "mount_point": "secretstuff/",
    "mount_running_version": "v0.19.0+builtin",
    "mount_type": "kv",
    "namespace": {
      "id": "root"
    },
    "operation": "read",
    "path": "secretstuff/data/foo",
    "remote_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "remote_port": 44202
  },
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "error": "hmac-sha256:22ba3377594e64f29f74a0c8a85527273972035cfead825780c3251ba7b108e1"
    },
    "mount_class": "secret",
    "mount_point": "secretstuff/",
    "mount_running_plugin_version": "v0.19.0+builtin",
    "mount_type": "kv"
  },
  "time": "2024-08-09T17:39:03.194458752Z",
  "type": "response"
}

If i use the token accessor to look up its capabilities it also confirms that this token will get a deny response accessing this path
$ vault token capabilities --accessor 1RDKHDF8KVpTdB0jGey5fSr3 secretstuff/data/foo
deny

So Your policy is good, it will deny any access to secretstuff/data paths inline with vault policy matching process.
So if you are getting allowed, then maybe look at the default policy if its somehow allowing the access. You can also look at the audit logs (in my case I am using syslog) to look at responses that grant access. in those cases the audit log will tell you which policy actually allowed the access. So when I access the kv mount point which is allowed by the * glob. I can look at the audit log and see that the policy result is allow and it will tell me which policy allowed it.
  "auth": {
    "accessor": "hmac-sha256:8f2f0506e37dbd0d1d0116f68ce155c41b6d7efa841fb6afb1697b179daa6ce6",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:d011436b2aa7d8e56bf1f466e2488cb986c326890f12a5896c3a3b13288c59eb",
    "display_name": "userpass-ops_test",
    "entity_id": "58a235d9-5f6d-3158-d64f-2af898e4bae7",
    "metadata": {
      "username": "ops_test"
    },
    "policies": [
      "default",
      "ops"
    ],
    "policy_results": {
      "allowed": true,
      "granting_policies": [
        {
          "name": "ops",
          "namespace_id": "root",
          "type": "acl"
        }
      ]
    },

I appreciate this maybe doesn't solve the issue so might not be an answer but it was to big to explain as a comment. I am also happy to chat through this offline directly.
